# How to run SQL Server Management Studio Express from CD

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Is it possible to run SQL Server Management Studio Express from CD without installing it on the computer?

I need it sometimes to provide support for the client but do not want to install/uninstall it.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for some kind of portable 'SQL Server' client tool that you can simply carry around on a USB drive, etc. Not very likely Microsoft provides something like that but perhaps something equivalent exists out there. (Perhaps SQLCMD is portable as suggested by: [CONT..]

Comment: [...CONT] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470827/how-to-run-sql-server-management-studio-express-from-cd#470871

Comment: I recommend using:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496898/decent-simple-sql-server-client/2497195#2497195

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing basic support, you can simply use [SQLCMD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) to run queries/procs.  Other than that I don't think there is any way to run it without installing it.  There are a few questions on SO about alternatives to Management Studio that you may be able to install on a cd/key though.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't you have to install it

can you not connect remotely maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install it as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL 2000 isqlw.exe is standalone, IIRC, and can manage SQL 2005 to a point.

Comment: I wasn't able to make it work even after I have added other .DLL requested by .EXE